# Does hash function djb2 have java version?

Tags: java, hash

I saw that java can't handle unsigned long...
If yes, can any one post the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you going to be interoperating with languages featuring unsigned types?  If not you can probably just use the standard java long without a problem.  It will probably overflow anyways (as per the discussion here [djb2 Hash Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571683/djb2-hash-function)) but that's not a problem.

Here's a [PermissionSet class](http://www.koders.com/java/fid168E7CA15EC6049221D26DE6AEF08F6CEFC2FBDF.aspx) in the wild using this implementation.  Don't forget that a hashCode in Java needs to return an integer anyways, so the lack of an unsigned long should not make a difference - there will just be fewer possible values that the function takes on.