# Are hash functions supposed to return the numerical value of the hash or that value % numBuckets?

Tags: php, hash

I'm using the following hash function

```
function hash_djb2($str){
    $hash = 5381;
    $length = strlen($str);

    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $hash = (($hash << 5) + $hash) + ord(strtolower($str[$i])) - 96;        
    }
    return $hash;
}
```

Am I supposed to return `$hash` or `$hash % $numBuckets` where `$numBuckets` is the number of buckets in the hash table?

The former would return really large numbers and make hash collision impossible while the latter returns only values between 0 and `$numBuckets`-1 but makes hash collision possible

Comment: What's `$numBuckets`?

Comment: The number of buckets in the hash table

Comment: Based on a [c version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571683/djb2-hash-function) i would say `$hash`

Comment: I think that c version is just an example of djb2 and how it works.  It's not a working example of djb2 for the HashTable class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `hash_djb2()` (should) cover the whole spectrum of an integer value, so if you're implementing a hash chain (i.e. limited number of buckets), you would need to use modulo to shorten the range.

Btw, the risk of hash collisions is only reduced if you decide to only use the function output; making the range smaller obviously increases that risk. You're supposed to manage that risk by allowing multiple items to be stored under the same hash value.

Comment: Yah I know, I'm using a linked list to allow multiple values to be stored in the hash value. http://www.relisoft.com/book/lang/pointer/8hash.html

Comment: @user784637 Okay. Btw, I hope this is just for educational purposes :)

Comment: Yah of course! I don't have a CS degree so I'm just trying to learn the building blocks of data structures like hash tables, linked lists, etc...