# Difficulty implementing djb2 hash function

Tags: c, hash, casting, hash-function

I'm trying to create a function for a hash table, but when I run my code I get a warning saying assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast.
My code is:

```
//from header file
//word_t is char*
typedef word_t* vc_ht_key;
typedef void *ht_key;

//in file
size_t hash(ht_key k) {
  unsigned long val = 5381;
  int c;
  while ((c = (*(vc_ht_key)k)++)) {
    val = ((val << 5) + val) + c;
  }
  return (size_t)val;
}
```

Sorry in advance for any missing information. I was given a generic hash table to work with making it impossible to post all of it here. I was hoping someone could explaining the type casting issue. e.g simply adding an (int) to the while line.

Comment: `(*(vc_ht_key)k)` is a `char*`. Is it supposed to be a `char*` or just a `char`?

Comment: here is a link to the source code I'm trying to use

Comment: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571683/djb2-hash-function)

Comment: Well the source code in the link and the source code in your question are different so clearly that is not the source code you're trying to use.

Comment: I'm pretty sure their the same function once I type cast k to be a char*, at least behavior wise.

Comment: But you aren't typecasting k to be a char*.

Comment: Then what am I typecasting k to be

Comment: `char**`, because `word_t` is `char*`, so `word_t*` is `char**`