# I keep getting a segmentation fault and I'm not sure why. I may be using the strcasecmp function incorrectly but I'm not sure

Tags: cs50

my code compiles but when i run it i get a segmentation fault. i have played around with the debugging tool in the cs50 ide and my mistake might be something with the use of the strcasecmp function but i can't tell what i've done wrong. any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

https://pastebin.com/mrASRwWk

// Implements a dictionary's functionality

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "dictionary.h"
 
// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;
 
// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 1000;
 
// Hash table
node *table[N];
 
// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{

    node* temp = NULL;
    int h = hash(word);
    temp = table[h];
   
    do
    {
        int result = strcasecmp(word, temp->word);
       
        if (result == 0)
        {
            return true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    while (temp->next != NULL);
   
    return false;
}
 
/* Adapted by Neel Mehta from
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571683/djb2-hash-function.
 */
 
// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
 {
     unsigned long hash = 5381;
 
     for (const char* ptr = word; *ptr != '\0'; ptr++)
     {
         hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + tolower(*ptr);
     }
 
     return hash % N;
 
 }
 
// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
// create global count variable
int count;
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dict == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open dictionary.\n");
        return false;
    }
   
    char temp[46];
    count = 0;
 
   // read one word at a time
    while (fscanf(dict, "%s", temp)!= EOF)
    {

        node* n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            free(n);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            int h = hash(temp);
            strcpy(n->word, temp);
            n->next = table[h];
            table[h] = n;
            count++;
        }
    }
    fclose(dict);
    return true;
}
 
// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    if (!count || count == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return count;
    }
}
 
// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    node* temp = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
    {
        temp = table[i];
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            table[i] = temp->next;
            free(temp);
            temp = table[i];
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please, add some other tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program will seg fault in check when the text word hashes to an empty list. When table hasn't been populated for a particular index, this `table->word` gives a seg fault. (Any reference to `table->next` will also seg fault). Keep that in mind and review `unload` too.