# Why is my program leaking memory in C despite using free() at some point in the program?

Tags: c, cs50

My Speller program is working perfectly fine except for a memory leak that I can't seem to wrap my head around. I have already satisfied every other check50 requirement and I would very much appreciate someone's help regarding my code logic. Thank you in advanced to whoever would dedicate some of their time to helping me! Anyways, here is the code:

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 1000;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// File pointer
FILE *read;

// Node pointer
node *new_node;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // Input word into hash function
    int word_index = hash(word);

    // Check if word is in dictionary
    for (node *tmp = table[word_index]; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(word, tmp->word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
// Credits to Neel Mehta from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571683/djb2-hash-function
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    unsigned long index = 5381;

    for (const char *ptr = word; *ptr != '\0'; ptr++)
    {
        index = ((index << 5) + index) + tolower(*ptr);
    }

    return index % N;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // Initialize word
    char dict_word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Open file for reading
    read = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (read == NULL)
    {
        // Terminate program
        printf("Cannot open dictionary\n");
        return false;
    }

    // Loop until end of file
    while (fscanf(read, "%s", dict_word) != EOF)
    {
        // Initialize node pointer
        new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (new_node == NULL)
        {
            // Terminate program
            free(new_node);
            printf("Insufficient memory storage\n");
            return false;
        }

        // Copy word into node pointer
        strcpy(new_node->word, dict_word);

        // Set pointer to null
        new_node->next = NULL;

        // Call upon hash function
        int word_index = hash(new_node->word);

        // Index result into hash table
        if (table[word_index] == NULL)
        {
            // Open node
            table[word_index] = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            // !Open node
            new_node->next = table[word_index];
            table[word_index] = new_node;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // Iterate through the whole hash table
    int word_counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (table[i] == NULL)
        {
            // Skip iteration
        }
        else
        {
            // Check how many words
            for (node *tmp = table[i]; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next)
            {
                word_counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return word_counter;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // Iterate through the hash function
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (table[i] == NULL)
    {
        // Skip iteration
    }
        else
        {
            // Initialize pointers
            node *tmp_first = table[i];
            node *tmp_second = table[i]->next;

            // Iterate through the linked list
            while (tmp_second != NULL)
            {
                free(tmp_first);
                tmp_first = tmp_second;
                tmp_second = tmp_second->next;
            }
        }
    }
    free(new_node);
    fclose(read);
    return true;
}
```

Valgrind says that 56 bytes in 1 block is still reachable, specifically referring to:

```
new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

which is located in the load function. What I'm confused about is that I freed it at the end:

```
free(new_node);
```

yet it seems that it has no effect. This is my only problem left before being able to submit and receive a perfect score and I would like to understand why there is still a memory leak in that certain line. Thanks again!

Comment: It looks like `tmp_first` may still point to a valid node after your loop ends in the unload function. It also looks like you might have a double free since you free `new_node` but also assign it to a slot in the table. It probably shouldn't be a global.

Comment: Don't have a special case to free `new_node`. Just free everything in each `table` chain. In fact, you shouldn't be using a global variable for `new_node` at all. That doesn't make any sense because that node is linked into the `table` and should not get special treatment.

Comment: If you use clang-tools and more specifically scan-build you will get a step-by-step explanation of what is leaking memory and why.

Comment: The macro `LENGTH` is not defined in the posted code!    What is the contents of the header file: `Dictionary.h`?

Comment: regarding: `const unsigned int N = 1000;`  The posted code is C, not C++.  So much better to write: `#define N 1000`

Comment: OT: regarding: `read = fopen(dictionary, "r");` and `if (read == NULL)`   The C library contains the well known function: `read()`, exposed via `#include <unistd.h>`  It is best ( for readability and understanding) to not use well known function names for local variable names.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Cannot open dictionary\n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  And when the error is from a C library function should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred. Suggest: `perror( "fopen to read dictionary failed" );`  followed by `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT: the posted code is missing a `main()` function and most of the posted functions are never called.

Comment: there are lots of questions about: `cs50 pset5 speller.c` Suggest performing a search, similar to: `stackoverflow.com: cs50 pset5 speller.c`

Comment: regarding: *My Speller program is working perfectly fine except for a memory leak*  How can that possibly be true when it does not even compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues:

1. `new_node` shouldn't be a global. It should be local to the `load` function.
2. When freeing memory, you don't free the last element in each linked list.

Comment: There is MUCH MUCH more wrong with the posted code besides the two items you mention.

Answer (score 0):

running the posted code through a compiler results in:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled1.c" -o "untitled1.o" 

untitled1.c:24:7: error: variably modified ‘table’ at file scope
   24 | node *table[N];
      |       ^~~~~

untitled1.c: In function ‘check’:
untitled1.c:36:22: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘hash’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   36 |     int word_index = hash(word);
      |                      ^~~~

untitled1.c: At top level:
untitled1.c:51:14: error: conflicting types for ‘hash’
   51 | unsigned int hash(const char *word)
      |              ^~~~

untitled1.c:36:22: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘hash’ was here
   36 |     int word_index = hash(word);
      |                      ^~~~

untitled1.c: In function ‘hash’:
untitled1.c:57:40: warning: conversion to ‘long unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
   57 |         index = ((index << 5) + index) + tolower(*ptr);
      |                                        ^

untitled1.c:60:18: warning: conversion from ‘long unsigned int’ to ‘unsigned int’ may change value [-Wconversion]
   60 |     return index % N;
      |            ~~~~~~^~~

untitled1.c: In function ‘load’:
untitled1.c:98:26: warning: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘unsigned int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
   98 |         int word_index = hash(new_node->word);
      |                          ^~~~

untitled1.c: In function ‘size’:
untitled1.c:121:23: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  121 |     for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      |                       ^

untitled1.c:136:12: warning: conversion to ‘unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
  136 |     return word_counter;
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~

untitled1.c: In function ‘unload’:
untitled1.c:143:23: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
  143 |     for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      |                       ^

Compilation failed.
```

So how can it possibly be giving a 'run time' problem?

When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings

There are also several problems with the logic of the posted code, but you really need to get it to cleanly compile (and link) before getting into the logic.

One of the easiest ways to debug the logic is with a debugger, like `gdb` or an IDE, like `visual studio`.