# Why can a hash such as djb2, when used with a ulong, be larger than 32 bits

Tags: c, hash, bit

```
unsigned long hash(char *str) 
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;
    while ((c = *str++))
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */
    return hash % NUM_BUCKETS;
}
```

With this code, when you put in the function 20 letters(such as `zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz`) you get an output of a huge number. how does the long hold the numbers if it is restricted to only 32 bits?

Comment: `you get an output of a huge number` How _exactly_ do you check the size of the output? `printf(what here?)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [djb2 Hash Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571683/djb2-hash-function)

Answer (score 0):

You should first check that an `unsigned long` *is* 32 bits. If you're getting values above about (roughly) 4.2 billion, it's almost certainly wider than that<sup>(a)</sup>.

You can *check* this by compiling and running the following program:

```c
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n%zu\n", CHAR_BIT, sizeof(unsigned long));
    return 0;
}
```

The first value is the number of bits in a byte, the second the number of bytes in an `unsigned long`. Multiplying the two will therefore give you the number of bits in the `unsigned long` type.

On my system, I get `8` and `8`, indicating a 64-bit size.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The ISO C standard does not mandate an exact size for the original types found in C (though it may for things like `uint32_t`). In fact it doesn't directly even mandate the number of bits at all.

What is *does* mandate is the ***minimum range*** requirements which, for `unsigned long` is `0..4294967295` (the 4.2 billion I mentioned before).

However, an implementation is free to provide you with something larger, such as a 128-bit type, which would give you a range from zero up to about 10<sup>38</sup>, or a hundred million million million million million million.

As an aside, I *could* have used billions, trillions, or even quadrillions but:

- there's sometimes disagreement as to that actual powers of ten they represent; and
- the use of many "million" suffixes drives home the size more than a single rarely knows suffix like "undecillion" or "sextillion".

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned long` is *at least* 32 bits, but it can be larger. It's a 64-bit type with most compilers on most 64-bit processors except under Windows. So a function returning `unsigned long` can return a value that's larger than 2<sup>32</sup>.

However, the function you show is guaranteed to return a number in the range from `0` to `NUM_BUCKETS` inclusive. If you see a value that's larger than `NUM_BUCKETS`, what you're seeing is not a value returned by this function. Maybe there's a bug in your code. Make sure that you've enabled all reasonable warnings on your compiler and that you've resolved them correctly (not by blindly adding a cast). If you still don't understand your program's output, use a debugger and inspect intermediate values. If you *still* don't understand what your program is doing, you can ask online, with [complete code that reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).